# oracle regex match interval

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to find out all the name which contains minimum 2 consecutive a and not more then 3 consecutive a.

I written the quires but It not fulfill the requirement.

Please look the below quires

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME,'a{2,3}')
```

Output:
[image]

But I need only "Srikrushnaaa".

Thanks.

Comment: next time dont use images for test data, use [Text Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)  to make tables.

Comment: @Pragyan . . . Would the string `'Xaaxaaaaay'` match or not match?

Comment: Please come back and explain the rules to make the question clearer and finalize it.

Answer (score 3):

You may use

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME,'([^a]|^)a{2,3}([^a]|$)')
```

**Details**

- `([^a]|^)` - any char but `a` or start of string
- `a{2,3}` - 2 or 3 `a`s
- `([^a]|$)` - any char but `a` or end of string

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m3eADI/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(%5B%5Ea%5D%7C%5E)a%7B2%2C3%7D(%5B%5Ea%5D%7C%24)):

[image]

Comment: Seams to be a good regex if Oracle database regex's engine is also confirm these processing rules..

Comment: @RaymondNijland This regex is compliant with Oracle regex engine. I did not use non-capturing groups and lookarounds here.

Comment: Well regex does not really have a defined ANSI/ISO standard or a RFC this the reason behide mine comment.. i saw sometimes regex being tested on that same website and when used in the code and it didn't work like expected.

Comment: *" I did not use non-capturing groups and lookarounds here."* That's true it makes the regex compliant much better.

Comment: Except this matches `'Xaaxaaaaa'`

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer, but if the 'aaa' is in middle, how can we get

Comment: @GordonLinoff Then, it is a valid string as per requirements.

Comment: @Pragyan What do you mean by *but if the 'aaa' is in middle, how can we get*? Get what? What `aaa` in the middle? Show the exact example string and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

I would simply do:

```
WHERE FIRST_NAME LIKE '%aa%' AND
      FIRST_NAME NOT LIKE '%aaaa%'
```

Regular expressions don't seem to be needed for this.

Comment: *"Regular expressions don't seem to be needed for this."* +1 your right but *"minimum 2 consecutive a and not more then 3 consecutive a."*  should translate into ->  `WHERE ( FIRST_NAME LIKE '%aa%' OR FIRST_NAME LIKE '%aaa%' ) AND
      FIRST_NAME NOT LIKE '%aaaa%'` i believe?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am new to regular expression, so i want to achieve this using regular expression.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . Your expression is overly complicated.  If there are three together, then there are two together, so it matches my logic.

Comment: *"Your expression is overly complicated. If there are three together, then there are two together, so it matches my logic"* true offcource that is what you get when you are thinking (to) complicated most of the time then you are missing simplification sometimes.. if i could i would give a extra upvote for the simplification..

Answer (score 0):

`AND` a second `regexp_like` that checks for more than three `'a'`s.

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME,
       LAST_NAME
       FROM EMPLOYEES
       WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME,'a{2,3}')
             AND NOT REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME,'a{4,}');
```

Comment: Yes, we will get the answer, but I need only one regular expression not AND operator